# Download Facebook JS SDK

Tags: javascript

In order to speedup page loading I would like to download Facebook SDK.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5&appId=1187326234648590";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="button_count"></div>
```

How I Can download the complete library and use it from JavaScript source  file?

Comment: isn't the url in the middle of the code shown? it's not even templated...

Comment: I tested this but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function() {
  "use strict";

  var URLS = {
    facebookInit: "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"
  };

  myApp.initializeFbSdk = function(appId, version) {
    $.getScript(URLS.facebookInit, function() {
      FB.init({
        appId: appId,
        version: version
      });
    });
  };

  myApp.createFbSharePopup = function(url) {
    FB.ui({
      method: "share",
      href: url
    });
  };

  // other methods if needed
})();

$(document).ready(function() {
  myApp.initializeFbSdk(fbAppId, fbSdkVersion);

  //...

  myApp.createFbSharePopup("www.mysite.org");
});
```

Comment: Can you show me the full code. I don't get any result.